# Changing objects to null/other objects via reference

Tags: java

The following code below represents a binary tree with the main function being its tester.

The question is below the code and refers to the remove function which would've worked if the comments within were an actual part of it.

```
public class BTT {

    btnode root;

    private class btnode {
        Object data;
        btnode left, right;

        btnode(Object data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        btnode(Object data, btnode left, btnode right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "" + data;
        }
    }

    BTT() {
        root = null;
    }

    void add(Object data) {
        root = add(data, root);
    }

    btnode add(Object data, btnode N) {
        if(N == null) {
            return new btnode(data);
        }
        //=========================
        if((int) data > (int) N.data) {
            N.right = add(data, N.right);
        } else {
            N.left = add(data, N.left);
        }
        //=========================
        return N;
    }

    void printInorder() {
        printInorder(root);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void printInorder(btnode N) {
        if(N == null) {
            return;
        }

        printInorder(N.left);
        System.out.print(N.data + ", ");
        printInorder(N.right);
    }

    void remove(Object data) {
        /*root = */
        remove(data, root);
    }

    /*btnode instead of void*/void remove(Object data, btnode N) {
        if(N == null) {
            return /*null*/;
        }

        if((int) data > (int) N.data)
            /*N.right = */ {
            remove(data, N.right);
        } else if((int) data < (int) N.data)
            /*N.right = */ {
            remove(data, N.right);
        } else {//Object found
            if(N.left == null && N.right == null) {
                N = null;
            } else if(N.left != null && N.right == null) {
                N = N.left;
            } else if(N.left == null && N.right != null) {
                N = N.right;
            }
            //else//(irrelevant)
        }
        /*return N*/
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BTT BT1 = new BTT();
        BT1.add(1);
        BT1.add(3);
        BT1.add(2);
        BT1.add(4);
        BT1.printInorder();
        BT1.remove(1);
        BT1.printInorder();
    }
}
```

I understand that the reason that BTT's `remove` function isn't working is that when changing the `N` variables that refer to the `btnode`(s)s at hand, it merely changes the pointer `N` itself and not the content of the address of which it points at.

Is there any way to make that remove function work *without* adding the `btnode` returned values instead of `void`? Or is changing it to something like: `btnode remove(Object data, btnode N){...}` the only way?

Comment: Is the problem that you want to edit another object that this inside the remove-function?

Comment: I want to edit an object inside the remove function so that - for example - it would be equal to the next object to the right/left(if that's what you meant?).

Comment: To be more precise: I want to know whether you can change the content of the btnode pointers to different btnodes without using the method that the comments in the remove function suggest.
f.e: Something like N=N.right that would change the content of N and not simply change N to point at a different address.